# PyCharm debugger getting stuck on line

Tags: python, python-3.8

I'm new to the PyCharm debugger so I'm pretty sure I'm wrong about this, but I think it may be stopping on a line during debugging.

```
weights = self.model.get_weights()
diff = self.model.get_grad(data, labels, self.lamb)
```

I step the debugger over the first line and onto the second line, and then step into the `get_grad` call. This takes me to the `get_weights` function, which is a different function belonging to the same class (`Model`) as `get_grad`. I've searched through the entire document for places I'm calling something like

```
<model object>.get_weights = <model object>.get_grad
```

that would switch the pointers to the functions (based on my perhaps incorrect understanding of Python), but I can't find any lines like this. Any recommendations on where this bug might come from?

Comment: Try putting an `assert self.model.get_weights != self.model.get_grad` between the two lines,

Comment: `get_weights()` was on the line above, maybe you have made code changes during debugging, moving everything one line down?